# Integration between Enterprise Architect (EA) and Microsoft Test Manager (MTM)

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, integration, enterprise-architect, microsoft-test-manager

Does anyone know if there's an existing integration between Sparx Enterprise Architect (EA) and Microsoft Test Manager (MTM - part of the Visual Studio/TFS suite)

We would like to define our tests in EA, but the management of the test execution should be in MTM

Comment: You would need to speak to Sparx. MSFT does not generaly create integrations to third party commercial products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the answer at this moment is **no**.

I might need to write it myself.